# Transfer files between Amazon S3 buckets in Unity

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to transfer files between S3 buckets inside Unity, and running into cryptic errors that I can't find documentation on. Both buckets belong to the same account.

Whenever I create an asset, I upload it to S3 servers in the Dev Bucket, which works great. When I'm ready to commit assets, I want to go through a list of assets missing from the Prod Bucket and transfer them over from the Dev Bucket. From my research, `IAmazonS3. CopyObjectAsync()` is the function that should do this task. The `IAmazonS3.CopyObject()` [function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingNetSDK.html) is **not** available in Amazon's Unity SDK.

Here's the code I call while trying to copy the object:

```
public void TestCopy()
{
    var request = new CopyObjectRequest()
    {
        SourceBucket = mLoginData.DevBucket,
        SourceKey =  "myPic.jpg",
        DestinationBucket = mLoginData.ProdBucket,
        DestinationKey = "myPic.jpg"
    };

    AWSConfigs.HttpClient = AWSConfigs.HttpClientOption.UnityWebRequest;

    Client.CopyObjectAsync(request,(responseObj) =>
    {
        if (responseObj.Exception == null)
        {
            ResultText.text += "Copied Object";
        }
        else
        {
            ResultText.text += "Got Exception: \n" + responseObj.Exception.ToString();
        }
    });
}
```

This results in a "Moved" error code that isn't mentioned in the [Amazon Error Code documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html):

```
Got Exception: 
Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: Error making request with Error Code Moved and Http Status Code Moved. No further error information was returned by the service. Response Body: Encountered invalid redirect (missing Location header?) ---> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.UnityRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1[System.String].GetResponseCallbackHelper (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException (IExecutionContext executionContext, Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException exception) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1[T].Handle (IExecutionContext executionContext, System.Exception exception) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException (IExecutionContext executionContext, System.Exception exception) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsyncCallback (IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I know that I'm set up correctly because I'm able to view/list buckets, upload/list/delete files to both buckets, etc. It's critical that the solution executes from the Unity Editor.

Comment: Are these new buckets?

Comment: No, these are buckets that already have a lot of things in them, being used for the past 4 months or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that CopyObjectAsync needs to use an instance of the IAmazonS3 Client that's configured with the destination region, not the source region. Changing this allowed the copy just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on extensive experience working with the S3 API directly, I'm reasonably confident that this is your error:

> `PermanentRedirect`
>
> The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Send all future requests to this endpoint.
>
> `301 Moved Permanently`

I believe the underlying library is hiding this from you and the `Moved` error is that library's interpretation of the 301 error.  Why it would do this makes no sense, but then again that's why I prefer to work directly with the S3 REST API.

```
Encountered invalid redirect (missing Location header?)
```

This is consistent with the documented behavior.

> To help you find these errors during development, this type of redirect does not contain a Location HTTP header that allows you to automatically follow the request to the correct location. Consult the resulting XML error document for help using the correct Amazon S3 endpoint.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Redirects.html

If there's a way to get your hands on that XML response body, it might be helpful.

This error is common within the first few minutes of bucket creation if you access a bucket using the global (non-region-specific) endpoint and the bucket is in a region other than us-east-1, which is why I asked if the buckets were new.

If the buckets are not in us-east-1, you likely need to be passing a region somewhere in your code, because the error above suggests your requests are arriving at the wrong regional endpoint.

Comment: It so happens that the source bucket is in US-West-2 and the destination bucket in US-East-1. I only just found this out, and it seems to concur with your conclusion. I'll try passing a region code in the copy function, along with reading up how to transfer between regional buckets. Thanks for the direction!